# Embedded script does not recognize the variable defined in external script

Tags: javascript

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>VAST Client JS Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="src/vast-client-browser.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // display a text on the page.
      document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "Step 1";

      var vastClient = new VAST.VASTClient();

      // display a text on the page.
      document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "Step 2";

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I put [the js file](https://github.com/dailymotion/vast-client-js/blob/master/dist/vast-client-browser.min.js) into the src folder.

However, it doesnt work as expected.

As you see above, on my HTML file, I print "Step 1" and "Step 2" text.
However, it does not show the text "Step 2" since It was used after using the variable in my JS file.

[image]

Also, I get a warning message like "'VAST' is assigned a value but never used."

Please check out my [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-waterfall-3lgho9?file=/index.html).

What could I be missing?

Comment: I created an npm project, downloaded the files and ran parcel. I get `Error: XHRURLHandler: (0)` because the springserve server doesn't allow cors. In other words: using VAST works fine.

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisG But without using npm, why doesn't the above code give the same result? what is missing?

Comment: I moved the folder inside my apache's htdocs and opened the file via http://localhost/... and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Hmm. So why is the demo in codesandbox not working then? Could you please check out the demo @ChrisG https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-waterfall-3lgho9?file=/index.html

Comment: I did and don't know but I found that changing "App1" in the source had no effect so not sure what's wrong with the sandbox.